# wso2 integrator 6.1 No available task nodes for resolving a task location

Tags: wso2, integrator

I am running a clustered set up of WSO2 ESB integrator. When trying to add scheduled tasks, I get the below error:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2018-11-12 15:41:59,409] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager} -  Scheduling task [[NTask::-1234::InvokeASGReadEmailBodyTask]::synapse.simple.quartz] FAILED. Error: No available task nodes for resolving a task location {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager}
>   In axis2.xml I have defined the nodes as worker and manager in the below tag: respectively:

Adding one more point in axis2.xml I had changed clusteringPattern as **WorkerManager** from nonWorkerManager

Comment: have you setup your task service mode in the tasks-config.xml ?  https://docs.wso2.com/display/Admin44x/Configuring+the+Task+Scheduling+Component#ConfiguringtheTaskSchedulingComponent-Step2:Configuringaclusteredtaskserver

Comment: yes I have done that. <taskServerMode>CLUSTERED</taskServerMode>
<taskServerCount>1</taskServerCount>
even keeping taskServerMode as AUTO does not work

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason why you are getting this error is, when you start the manager node as the first member NTASK tries to find any available workers to run the task. Because the task will not run on the manager node. It will run on either worker nodes or in standalone nodes. 
Since there is no worker nodes up and running when the manager node is started, this error gets printed.

Therefore make sure that the worker nodes are started before starting up the manager node.

Comment: I don't think that is the case because even when I try to add the task directly into the worker nodes I see the same error in them.